# Ember route.connections is undefined while render on error events

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'd like to render message about server error. I create special route that present error message view. At the same time I don't want redirect to that route's url to be able to reload current page. So I decided to use function render in application route.

```
// application/route.js
actions: {
  error: function(error, transition) {
    if (error.errors) {
      return this.render('server-error.internal');
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

It's working correctly when I redirect do page with error from other application's route that load correctly. When I type manually url of page with error I take error

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

As I checked it's about uninitialized route's property named 'connections'. I found similar issues on github, but I couldn't find solution. I'll be grateful for any help.

I'm using ember-cli: 2.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found workaround for this issue, that could be useful for somebody with similar issue. Instead of using `error event` I used `error substate`. [See documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/). Theoretically it should work the same, but in this case it doesn't.

I created new route `error` and inside `renderTemplate` method I'm setting target url, checking type of error (with custom function) and rendering proper template:

```
// app/pods/error/route.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    const transition = this.get('router.router.activeTransition');
    const url = this.get("router").generate(transition.targetName);
    this.get("router").router.updateURL(url);

    if (model.errors) {
      if (is404Error(model.errors)) {
        return this.render('server-error.not-found');
      } else if (is500Error(model.errors)) {
        return this.render('server-error.maintenance');
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```